# multidimensional list search

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, multidimensional-array

Help with code below using a multidimensional list i need to search each row for characters in the array and locate a word and return the location of the 1st letter. This works perfectly for one letter but when i try a word that starts with a letter in the array but not the whole word it doesn't work. Can someone help me here. I can see that I start with x=word[0] but whenever I try to increment the value for x to include i keep messing up. Basically I need 'aca' to return [2, 1] as that's the start of the 1st char in the word but I ara is entered NONE should be the return value.

```
def find_word_horizontal(crosswords,word):

    word=str(word)
    x=word[0]
    char=0
    crosslen=len(crosswords)
    found=False

    for row in crosswords:
        r=crosswords.index(row)
        wordcount=len(word)
        for i in range(0, len(row)):
            if wordcount<2:
                if row[i]==x:
                    r=crosswords.index(row)
                    found=True
                    print([r, i])
                    return([r, i])
            else:
                for i in range(0, len(row)):
                    for let in word:
                        if row[i]==let and char<=wordcount:
                            char+=1
                        if char==wordcount:
                            t=0
                            for c in row:
                                if c==x:
                                    found=True
                                    r=crosswords.index(row)
                                    print([r, t])
                                    return([r, t])
                                t+=1
                            char=0
                        else:
                            continue
    if found==False:
        print(None)
        return None

crosswords=[['s', 'd', 'o', 'g'], ['c', 'u', 'c', 'm'], ['a', 'c', 'a', 't'], ['t', 'e', 't', 'k']]
word='aca'
find_word_horizontal(crosswords,word)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code *and* accurately describe the problem.  "It doesn't work" and "I keep messing up" are not problem descriptions.  Single-letter variable names and no descriptive comments leave your code as a guessing game to others.

Comment: Also, why are you expecting [2,1] when the word starts at [2,0]?  Position [2,1] is the 'c'.  Your code already produces [2,0] for anything starting with an 'a' -- which is a start.

Comment: You might also pick up a few tips from [How to Debug](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've scanned your program and I *think* I've found the conceptual problem.

It appears that you mis-handle **found**: you set it (to **True**) as soon as you find a single character that matches.  If later letters don't match, you have no way to clear **found** (to **False**).

First of all, I suggest that you take a higher view of the problem: look for the entire word at once.  Join the letters of the row into a string, and then use the **find** method:

```
whole_row = ''.join(row)
found_at = whole_row.find(word)
if found_at >= 0:
    return([r, found_at])
```

This can replace much of your central logic.  If you want the Pythonic short-cut, you can combine the first two lines above -- or one, if you want to pull a trick with optimization or duplicate a call.  I don't recommend it yet.

---

Please use descriptive variable names.  Something with a single letter should have no personality and be used for only a tight loop.  Don't mis-name things: **char** should be a single character, but you've made it an integer.

You've messed up the value of a loop index: while **i** is still active in the **for** loop at line 11, you then reuse it as a loop index at line 19.  This destroys its original use.

Why do you both print and return the result?

Why do you set r to the row number ... multiple times?  If you need the row number, then simply run your outer loop thusly:

```
for row_num in range(len(crosswords)):
    row = crosswords[row_num]
```

... and that's the last you have to manipulate either of these.  You appear to have done a similar thing with **c** and **t** in your innermost loop.

I hope this is enough to get you moving forward, and helps you tighten your programming somewhat.

Comment: Thanks mate for the help I'm definitely going to try and rework using the points above you help has be very much appreciated.

Comment: When you get through this problem, remember to "accept" an answer: SO gets to nicely retire the question; you get points back, as does the person who wrote the answer.  Remember that it's also okay to write a summary answer to combine all the help, and accept your own submission.  Up-voting the people who helped is good practice, too.